# Only use HTTPS for main site and HTTP for subdomains

Tags: htaccess, subdomain, https, security-certificate

I have a few static files on a `i.` subdomain but I don't have an SSL certificate and for its use it doesn't need one, however when I try to access it - it redirects for `https` which throws up an error and doesn't work.

I am currently using this in my `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

What is needed to make it ignore the `i.` subdomain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another condition to exclude the subdomain:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^i\.
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Presumably the `www` canonicalisation is already handled elsewhere?

This should probably be a 301 (permanent) redirect, rather than a 302 (temporary).

There is no need to capture the `RewriteRule` pattern (ie. `(.*)`) unless you are using it in the substitution.

Comment: @OfficialAntarctica serving static files from a HTTP sub domain to your HTTPS site means your main site will notify people that your site is not secure... Do yourself a favour and use a proper CDN with SSL, a sub domain serving files is no where near as fast as a dedicated CDN with multiple locations throughout the world.

Comment: @SimonHayter I came to that conclusion an hour ago, the subdomain will be `https`